# intermittent failures with SelectByLocation in an ArcPy addin

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin, select-by-location, error-999999

ArcGIS 10.2, Windows 10

this is the line that fails:

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(WRS_layer, "INTERSECT", gridLayer, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

The WRS_layer is in a file gdb, the gridLayer is in an SDE gdb. Both are polygon feature classes.  SDE layers are being edited by a user-initiated edit session, but in this addin button there is no arcpy.da.Editor.  The SelectByLocation will work fine for a while, and then starts giving an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...\ESRI\Desktop10.2\AssemblyCache\{1E...D8E}\NORDIS_Landsat.py", line 432, in onClick
   arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(WRS_layer, "INTERSECT", progressLayerName, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6812, in SelectLayerByLocation
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
General function failure
General function failure [WRS2_Nordis]
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).
```

Here is the referenced line in management.py

```
6806      from arcpy.geoprocessing._base import gp, gp_fixargs
6807    from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
6808    try:
6809        retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.SelectLayerByLocation_management(*gp_fixargs((in_layer, overlap_type, select_features, search_distance, selection_type), True)))
6810        return retval
6811    except Exception, e:
6812        raise e
```

Arcmap doesn't crash, but only a restart of ArcMap solves the problem. I don't think this is a code problem, but I hope that someone else has experienced something similar and can suggest a cause and/or solution.

EDIT: as requested, here is the top part of the button's code immed after def onClick(self)

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
# SET SOME VARIABLES
Error = False
WRS_layer          = "WRS2_Nordis"
WRS_fields         = ["PR"]
username           = getpass.getuser().lower()
rastersPresent     = []
rastersMissing     = []

# 0. VERIFY THAT THE REQUIRED LAYERS ARE PRESENT IN THE MXD.
print
layersPresent = []
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    layersPresent.append(lyr.name)
for lyrReqd in (WRS_layer, progressLayerName):
    if not lyrReqd in layersPresent:
        Error = True
        print "ERROR: cannot find layer  ", lyrReqd, "  in the TOC."

# 1. GET THE SELECTED GRID CELL
d = arcpy.Describe(progressLayerName)
if len(d.FIDSet) == 0:
    ProgressGrid_Select = 0
else:
    ProgressGrid_Select = len(d.FIDSet.split(";"))
if ProgressGrid_Select <> 1:
    print " You have", str(ProgressGrid_Select), " ProgressGrid cells selected  -- should be exactly 1."
    Error = True

# 2. GET THE INTERSECTING WRS SCENES
# make a WRS list of lists, with PathRow

if not Error:
    # SelectLayerByLocation HONOURS THE SELECTION SET IN in_layer
    print 'DEBUG: attempting SelectLayerByLocation_management(WRS_layer, "INTERSECT", progressLayerName, "", "NEW_SELECTION")'
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(WRS_layer, "INTERSECT", progressLayerName, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
    #  make list of WRS scenes, with PR (data type Long)
    WRS_scenes = []
    # SearchCursor (in_table, field_names, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, {sql_clause})
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(WRS_layer,WRS_fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            WRS_scenes.append(row[0])

    if len(WRS_scenes) == 0:
        print "No WRS_scenes intersect with selected Progress Grid cell."
        Error = True
    else:
        print "Found " + str(len(WRS_scenes)) + " WRS scenes for selected progress cell:"
        WRS_scenes.sort()
        prs = ''
        for pr in WRS_scenes:
            prs += ("  " + str(pr))
        print prs
    print
```

Comment: Those cursed ERROR 999999 messages. This error could mean *anything* that the developer didn't anticipate originally. Try calling repair geometry on your gridLayer and WRS_layer *feature class* just in case a bowtie or incorrect ring orientation has the selection engine confused. If there's changes in these datasets expected call as part of the script or if they're static run repair in catalog just once on both.

Comment: Is this in any loop in your addin or does the user have to press a button or click on the map to run a tool each time.  Are you cleaning up everything before completing each button press or tool operation?  Do you have an extension going?  With at least 432 lines of code in your addin you more than likely have created code than is a bit more complex sequence than a simple SelectLayerByAttribute operation.  The greater the complexity, the more likely you are not cleaning up after yourself.  Also, is the user able to select more features than SDE memory is configured to return?

Comment: Can you please include a snippet around line 432 of your code rather than from management.py?

Comment: I wonder if it could be a projection/coordinate system issue. Do they have the same spatial reference? Also, turning off background processing sometimes works better for more complex geoprocessing http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00210000003q000000

Comment: @Micheal OK, I've manually repaired geometry on the WRS_layer, it's not editable so I shouldn't need to call it in the script.  The gridLayer is in the SDE, so can't repair geometry there, it's supposed to be handled by the SDE.

Comment: @Richard This code isn't part of a loop.  The user selects a poly in the gridLayer, clicks a button to run the code once through. If the user selects more than one poly, the code stops gracefully before the selbyLoc starts. Also, the SelByLoc should only be able to return 10 polys max. Both inputs have < 20 vertices max per polygon.
Yes, I have extensions going in 2 different toolbars: one is listensing for onStartEditing &
onStopEditing, the other for onEditorSelectionChanged.  But what do you mean by "cleaning up after yourself"?

Comment: @dslamb The 2 input layers are in different projections, but this has never caused a problem before, been using the same setup in another project for 2 years with 5 editors. (Will fix it anyway.)

Comment: The selection code by Esri is not likely to be the cause of your problem, the code you have surrounded it with is the likely source of the problem.  For example, I put arcpy,da,editor code around a call to an Esri built-in button that managed its own Editor operations, so after running once successfully it failed every time after that.  When I removed my editor code from that button call it ran perfectly, but I still needed the editor code for my own custom buttons.

Comment: Now that I see your code I have no idea where the WRS_Layer variable came from.  How was the variable initialized?  Is it a global variable?  Add code that checks to make sure the WRS_Layer variable is actually a valid layer before using it with the select code.

Comment: The code is not logically arranged to fully avoid the failures you are testing for, since you could have failed to find a layer that matches the progressLayerName value in your first test.  But your code will always try to describe the progressLayerName layer even if that layer is not present in the map.  All code should be skipped after Error = True in the first section or you should directly test for just the progressLayerName before running the second failure test.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I was trying to be concise, omitted the SET SOME VARIABLES section -- I've edited the code above.  But the presence of WRS_Layer is confirmed in "step 0".

Comment: (just noticed request to chat -- wasn't aware I had triggered this, so have deleted it)